# Why is .setFormulaR1C1 correctly copying the formula, but it is not evaluating correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is evaluating to an error, but an IFERROR added is working. If I copy and paste the formula added during function execution, back into the cells, it works fine. There is no difference between the formula pasted and what is working. The cells are formatted to number.

I want the formula to updater and evaluate properly.

I have tried updating it to number after, but only re-pasting in the same formula works. I haven't found this issue anywhere else.

```
function populateFormula(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sheet.getSheets()[0];

  var cells = sheet.getRange('C3:C1000');
  sheet.getRange('C3:C').activate();
  sheet.getActiveRange().setFormulaR1C1('=(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],\'Main 
  Report \'!A:Z,5,false))');
```

It simply doesn't work as you would think.

Comment: Try using setFormula() instead of setFormulaR1C1(). However, setting the range to !A:Z gives an out of bound error to me. Can you share an example of your Sheet?

Comment: Sure, thankyou, here is a link to a similar situation I made but with no sensitive info: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YiE_mXFnlxJbj_rw3xx0nG1s2xivt_RGzRgGbOM4A10/edit#gid=0

As you can see, the formula being pasted in is showing as exactly the same as the one I manually copied on the first row - however they are being evaluated differently.


99% sure this is an unintended bug, but just wanted to be sure. Can I achieve the same results of copying a cell-specific formula without R1C1?

Comment: Yes, I'm explaining it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use

`sheet.getActiveRange().setFormula('=VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],Data2!A:Z,3,false)');`

Instead of

`sheet.getActiveRange().setFormulaR1C1('=VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],Data2!A:Z,3,false))');`

The reason is that even if `setFormulaR1C1` requires R1C1 notation (`R[0]C[-2]`), as you provided, you are also using `Data2!A:Z` which is [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).